# jQuery Setup and issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you set up jQuery in ColdFusion? I have downloaded 2.1.1.js created a js folder file and call the library like so .. `<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>` I am trying this code but for some reason I cannot get this to work any suggestions or help?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('span.date').each(function() { 
            var dateFormat = $(this).text()
            var dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM/DD/YYYY', new Date(dateFormat));
            //alert(dateFormat);
            $(this).html(dateFormat + "<br>");
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does the [browser's console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) say? Any messages?

Comment: Yeah you need both jQuery Core and jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Do you have other javascript files in that directory?  If you use a similar script tag, can you access the functions therein?

Comment: what does this have to do with ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add `jQuery UI` from this page: http://code.jquery.com/. You need both:

```
jQuery-ui CSS (pick a theme that fits your design or appeals to you)
jQuery-ui JS
```

Examples:

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css
```

And then your code would need to change per the [jQuery UI Datepicker API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Your code would not work as it is. Take a look at various examples here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and let us know if you still need help.

Comment: The [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) page tells you what versions of jQuery work with the latest version of jQuery UI ... a lot to take in but it will save you days of frustration. Take your time to understand the API docs.

Comment: You need to load the jQuery UI CSS

Comment: @Bauer adding the jQuery UI css should fix the _ugliness_. Here is an example [JavaScript fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u81qcja5/) Notice that I had to include the jQuery UI stuff (under External Resources on the right side).

Comment: There's an image folder that goes with the CSS; when you link to a CDN for the CSS, you never have to worry about downloading that folder. Download a zip file from: http://jqueryui.com/download/all/ to locate the folder or link to a CDN for the CSS.